# How to map Address field module sub fields (City, State, etc.) to specific (individual) fields in Salesforce?

Tags: 8

Address module: https://www.drupal.org/project/address
Usually Salesforce mapping doesn't allow to add Address module subfields in the mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can resolve this by using typed_data module. https://www.drupal.org/project/typed_data
This is a required module for Salesforce Suite installation.

In the Field Type select Properties,Extended
then select the name of the field associated the Address field Module corresponding to the Salesforce field.

[image]